# URI routing from controller to view - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am new to codeigniter ,

I want to redirect Login page request to this route

$route['login'] = 'TravelApi/login/';

So now http://localhost.com/codeigniter/login request should route through controller/TravelApi.php 's TravelApi class 's login() function.

**Controller**

```
public function login(){

        $contents['login_url'] = $this->googleplus->loginURL();
        $this->load->view('frontend/login',$contents);
}
```

My question is :

When request routes through above controller and then goes to frontend/login.php -- login.php file gets loaded but without header and footer.

But when I remove this route from config/routes.php

```
$route['login'] = 'TravelApi/login/';
```

then request does not route through controller and directly goes to frontend/login.php . and here it loads login.php file with header and footer.

But my need is to route from controller. and load view file with header footer.

So why it does not load header footer when routes through my controller's function ?

**EDIT:**

I found a function in default controller welcome.php

```
public function pages($alias=NULL)
{   
    $page='frontend/'.$alias;
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/head'); // For Head Scripts
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/header', $this->common_menu('TopMenu')); // For Header Content
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/menus', $this->common_menu('MainMenu')); // For Menus
    $this->load->view($page);  
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/footer'); // For Footer Content
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/foot'); // For Footer Scripts

}
```

But still not clear that why it does not load header footer when routes through my controller's function ?

Comment: is your header and footer file separated ?

Comment: yes this files are views/frontend/common/header.php .I just found that there is a function in core controller which loads header and footer. I am editing my question

Answer (score 0):

You kind of answer your own question in your edit. The header and footer are located in seperate view files, and you need to load those too. So something like this should work:

```
public function login(){

    $contents['login_url'] = $this->googleplus->loginURL();
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/head'); // For Head Scripts
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/header', $this->common_menu('TopMenu')); // For Header Content
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/menus', $this->common_menu('MainMenu')); 

    $this->load->view('frontend/login',$contents);

// For Menus
    $page='frontend/'.$alias;
    $this->load->view($page);  
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/footer'); // For Footer Content
    $this->load->view('frontend/common/foot'); // For Footer Scripts
}
```

Note: The line `$this->load->view($page);` looks like it's probably the main content for the other page and here the main content should be `$this->load->view('frontend/login',$contents);`, if that's the case remove the $page view load.

Comment: footer view is loading properly. but menus are not loading and showing error. because menu is dynamic and fetching data from database. But still question is if I remove this route from config/routes.php then it directly goes to view/login.php and loads header footer well. so from where is is coming ?

Comment: I just noticed the $page variable was defined earlier in welcome.php, but it still leaves an $alias variable you'll have to define. And if you remove the route then it must be loading frontend/login.php

Comment: what should $alias contain ?

Comment: In the welcome controller it defaults to null, and accepts parameters passed in via the URL. But that doesn't seem like the best approach for a login page since if someone goes to domain.com/login your $page will be set to 'frontend/' which would create an error.